# Displaying non-txt with type in a readable fashion - is it possible?

Tags: windows, command-line

I've been making incremental steps into the cmd prompt and was playing with the type function. [According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/type), "type is a built in command which displays the contents of a text file." As a result, type will display the text within a txt within the cmd prompt, while returning garbage when attempting to display another type of file, like docx.

I was wondering, is it therefore impossible to display the text contents of other file types in the cmd prompt?

Please let me know if more information is required, and thanks in advance.

Comment: That is possible, given the right tools. For instance, you could create a script that opens a docx in Word in the background, saves it as a text file, and then displays that file. But with standard DOS commands such as `type`, the answer would be *no*.

Comment: Short Answer: No it is not possible. Type can display non text files but you will see garbage.

Comment: That's the answer I figured would be most likely. Thanks! Would either of you mind posting an official answer to that?